# Accessing host loopback interface from device?

Tags: android

I've been so far running my app exclusively in the emulator. I want to try it out on a real device. My app connects to a web service running on the localhost itself using the host loopback IP of '10.0.2.2'.

I have got the application deployed on my phone, but I don't know how to access a url like:
"http://10.0.2.2/xyz/controller/AppController.php" when the application is on the phone.

Basically, I want my phone to connect to the web server running on my machine. My machine is a dev machine and doesn't have a static ip. Is it possible?

I understand I can deploy my web app on a real server with static ip and use that in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a network routable address on your PC you can register it with a service like DynDNS, alternatively if you can connect with Wifi to your PC on your LAN, you can access it with that.

Comment: Note that 10.0.2.2 is a special address in the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use the Emulator with `"google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);` or with `"sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);` depending on the used sdk.

And connect to your local network ip (or computername) or with port forwarding the public ip (using ddns) of your router.